# Backup Time reduction question

Tags: oracle10g, database-backups

I am told that a full DB backup of DB size 65GB takes between 4-5hrs in ORacle 10g.
Is that normal ?

We have a separate program activity that would take about 1.5 hrs.
We need to perform a full backup and this program activity in a single session which means
5 + 1.5 = 6.5 hrs needed to perform this whole session.
But we are given a maximum of 5-hr activity change window.

Question 
1) Is there another way in ORacle 10g where we could backup the delta change occurred a DB
(but we dont know which tables are updated in the DB to backup specifically) between
2 days ? If so, how do we do it ?
2) Would it be easy to import those delta-changed tables in that DB in order to reduce the
backup time ? If so, how do we do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have seen 65G database take even  10 hrs. Backups are a very highly tunable medium.
the Backup rate depends on many factors including the medium its being backed up to . the setup i.e rman vs non rman . disk  vs tape . if you can add a little more facts to your  questions. a answer can be possible . 
Also Oracle 10g Introduced a plethora of optimizations in the backup area  like the Block change tracking file and the recover as. 
Details can be found in Oracle 10.2 [Backup & Recover Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/rcmconc1.htm#i1011539) 
Look at the incremental strategy as well as tuning backups area.